# Can we connect database with javascript for functional testing?

Tags: javascript, sql, functional-testing, postman

I made my RestAPI service, now i want to validate responses with my database using Javascript for functional testing.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You mean like connecting your postman test scripts to the database, is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes..correct.. is it possible with postman?@Ram 10

Comment: I suggest you create a data source API that accepts plain SQL queries through POST method and returns data in JSON format and then you can perform your validation to other APIs. Don't forget to remove the data source API before deploying your app in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn´t use client javascript to access databases for several reasons (bad practice, security issues, etc) but if you really want to do this, here is an example:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```